# Jmeter difference in Avg response time between GUI mode and non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am getting different average response time between `GUI` mode and `non-GUI` mode.

In `GUI-Mode` : 439 MS
`Non-GUI` : 1669 Ms.

With 1 thread, 1 RampupTime , 1 Loopcount.

Comment: Is the difference consistent (GUI-mode always faster than non-GUI) if you try this out multiple times?

Comment: Yes . I am seeing always GUI mode is faster.